# VLC quits itself automatically after playing video

Tags: vlc-media-player

My laptop is running Windows 10 32-bit, and already have VLC 2.2.4 installed.
Is there any way (from command line) to make VLC automatically quits itself after playing video?

I already tried something like "vlc --no-play-and-exit somecatvideo.mp4", and well it didn't work. VLC was still opened so I had to terminate it manually.

Comment: `--play-and-exit` works for me, as does `vlc://quit`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Is there any way (from command line) to make VLC automatically quits itself after playing video?**

On the command line just add `vlc://quit` on the end of your command.

e.g

`vlc path/url vlc://quit`